# Typescript modules load error

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use Typescript modules but I cant seem to get them loaded.
I keep getting this error message in my js file:

JavaScript runtime error: 'exports' is undefined

I have a ajax.ts file with this content:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
export * from './ajax';

export class TsTest 
{

}
```

This is how i try to import the module:

```
import  ma = require("./modules/ajax");
function Test()
{
}
```

I have also tried loading it like this:

```
import * as ma from "./modules/ajax";

function Test()
{

}
```

No matter how i do it, I get this runtime error in my js file:

```
 JavaScript runtime error: 'exports' is undefined
// in this line:
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Comment: I cant get any modules loaded in Typescript, I have done it following toturials from scratch. Can anyone really get Typescript modules loaded, I must be missing something obvious.. Any one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with you code is this export `export * from './ajax';`.
Create a index.ts file where you export your file, don't do it inside the ajax file

Comment: When I do that, the problem will just move to that file getting the same error

Comment: Not working, are you sure its not some loader script i am missing. What should handle the import / export?

Comment: Been reading about this, has gulp anything to do with typescript?